# Renaming the field or using the right filter with django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I accidentaly named one of the fields "type" with django. Is there a way to rename it or can I still use the filter for that 'type' I understand that 'type' is a built-in function and it tries to use it and gives me errors.

```
class CarType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    type = models.ForeignKey(CarType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    year_released = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', kwargs={"id": self.id})


class HydrogenView(ListView):
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(type='Hydrogen') <-- had to change to 
                                                           type__name='Hydrogen'


    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name = 'Hydrogen.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is **not** related to the builtin `type` at all. The problem is you write `.filter(type='Hyrdogen')`.

`type` is a foreign key to `CarType` so it expects an instance of the same or the id of it. You should do something like:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class HydrogenView(ListView):
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(type__name='Hyrdogen')
    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name = 'Hydrogen.html'
    
    # If you add an argument to your url pattern you can try something like below
    # def get_queryset(self):
    #     car_type = get_object_or_404(CarType, pk=self.kwargs['car_type_pk'])
    #     return Product.objects.filter(type=car_type)
```

Comment: had to change to queryset = Product.objects.filter(type__name='Hyrdogen') and it worked, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of the field:

```
product_type = models.ForeignKey(CarType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
```

then run

`python manage.py makemigrations` & then `python manage.py migrate`

Although if you're correctly referencing the model field, I am not sure that you should get an error.

Comment: getting "   raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (type) specified for Product
" after i change name and makemigrations